# Keras: "ValueError: Error when checking target"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a model, which will classify video to certain category.

For this I used pretrained model - InceptionV3 and trained it on my own data.  Training process was completed successfully, but when I tried to classify video I got the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (None, None, None, 3) but got array with shape (1, 1, 104, 2048)
```

However for prediction I used the same video as for training process.

Defined model:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rotation_range=10.,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    os.path.join('data', 'train'),
    target_size=(299, 299),
    batch_size=32,
    classes=data.classes,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    os.path.join('data', 'test'),
    target_size=(299, 299),
    batch_size=32,
    classes=data.classes,
    class_mode='categorical')

base_model = InceptionV3(weights=weights, include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# and a logistic layer
predictions = Dense(len(data.classes), activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=10,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Predictions:

```
#extract features from frames of video

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    features = extractor_model.extract(f)
    sequence.append(features)

np.save(sequence_path, sequence)

sequences = np.load("data_final.npy")

#convert numpy array tp 4 dimensions
sequences = np.expand_dims(sequences, axis=0)
sequences = np.expand_dims(sequences, axis=0)

prediction = model.predict(sequences)
```

Features extractor:

```
def extract(self, image_path):
    #print(image_path)
    img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(299, 299))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    # Get the prediction.
    features = self.model.predict(x)

    if self.weights is None:
        # For imagenet/default network:
        features = features[0]
    else:
        # For loaded network:
        features = features[0]

    return features
```

## Keras complains about the shape is not None...

However I expect to receive some predictions of the model, but got this error. Please help. Thanks

Comment: There are too many missing informations in your question. How is *model* defined? What about the data? Try to provide a minimal and runnable piece of code.

Comment: Your model expect input with shape of something like `(xxx,xxx,xxx,3)` and your `sequences` has shape of  `(1,1,104,2048)`

Comment: Yes, the problem is that 3 != 2048.

Comment: @marcoromelli I have edited question. Data is UCF101 dataset.

Comment: @kruxx Yes, I undertsand it. But what is the way to make a prediction pf this model?

Comment: For prediction, your input sequences should be in shape of `(len(features),299,299,3)`, you have to resize your `features`.

Comment: @kruxx I load `sequences` from `data.npy`. Here I stored all video features and shape of `sequences` is `(104, 2048)`

Comment: @IKKLX Can you show, how you extracting `features` here, `features = extractor_model.extract(f)`

Comment: @kruxx Yes, I have edited post again.

Comment: @IKKLX Why are you predicting again if you had did in `extract` function here `features = self.model.predict(x)`